# Drag file from list to desktop python

Tags: python, drag-and-drop, wxpython

I am writing a file management and one of the UI functionality is to allow user dragging an item in the list to the desktop folder or just desktop. After googling, I found there is only dragging into the list supported in wxpython but no related articles about my issue. Is there any possible solution to this or any additional library supporting this function?

Comment: What code do you have so far?  What UI are you using?

Comment: @Justanotherdunce I am using wxpython and I use the file manager framework here: http://zetcode.com/wxpython/skeletons/

Answer (score 2):

It took me a little Googling, but I found the answer: http://wxpython-users.1045709.n5.nabble.com/Creating-file-DropSource-programatically-td2344103.html

Oddly enough, it says the AddFile method is Windows only in the documentation, but I couldn't figure out if that was really true or not. Anyway, here's a simple example based on the original example you gave:

```
import wx
import os
import time

class MyListCtrl(wx.ListCtrl):
    def __init__(self, parent, id):
        wx.ListCtrl.__init__(self, parent, id, style=wx.LC_REPORT)

        files = os.listdir('.')

        self.InsertColumn(0, 'Name')
        self.InsertColumn(1, 'Ext')
        self.InsertColumn(2, 'Size', wx.LIST_FORMAT_RIGHT)
        self.InsertColumn(3, 'Modified')

        self.SetColumnWidth(0, 220)
        self.SetColumnWidth(1, 70)
        self.SetColumnWidth(2, 100)
        self.SetColumnWidth(3, 420)

        j = 0
        for i in files:
            (name, ext) = os.path.splitext(i)
            ex = ext[1:]
            size = os.path.getsize(i)
            sec = os.path.getmtime(i)
            self.InsertStringItem(j, "%s%s" % (name, ext))
            self.SetStringItem(j, 1, ex)
            self.SetStringItem(j, 2, str(size) + ' B')
            self.SetStringItem(j, 3, time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M', 
                                                   time.localtime(sec)))

            if os.path.isdir(i):
                self.SetItemImage(j, 1)
            elif ex == 'py':
                self.SetItemImage(j, 2)
            elif ex == 'jpg':
                self.SetItemImage(j, 3)
            elif ex == 'pdf':
                self.SetItemImage(j, 4)
            else:
                self.SetItemImage(j, 0)

            if (j % 2) == 0:
                self.SetItemBackgroundColour(j, '#e6f1f5')
            j = j + 1


class FileHunter(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, id, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, -1, title)
        panel = wx.Panel(self)

        p1 = MyListCtrl(panel, -1)
        p1.Bind(wx.EVT_LIST_BEGIN_DRAG, self.onDrag)
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer()
        sizer.Add(p1, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        panel.SetSizer(sizer)

        self.Center()
        self.Show(True)

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def onDrag(self, event):
        """"""
        data = wx.FileDataObject()
        obj = event.GetEventObject()
        id = event.GetIndex()
        filename = obj.GetItem(id).GetText()
        dirname = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(os.listdir(".")[0]))
        fullpath = str(os.path.join(dirname, filename))

        data.AddFile(fullpath)

        dropSource = wx.DropSource(obj)
        dropSource.SetData(data)
        result = dropSource.DoDragDrop()
        print fullpath


app = wx.App(0)
FileHunter(None, -1, 'File Hunter')
app.MainLoop()
```

Tested on Windows 7, Python 2.6 and wxPython 2.8.12.1

Comment: It is true that this is only windows command as in Mac it cannot work

Comment: I'd ask on the wxPython users list to see if there are any equivalent methods for Mac / Linux then

Comment: Is there any news about mac support of this function?

Comment: It may work on Mac in the 2.9 series. Occasionally the docs don't get updated very quickly.

Comment: Tried the latest  wxPython (classic) 2.9.4. and still not working. I guess there is no way to work it out on Mac...

Comment: You should ask on the wxPython mailing list about it. There may be some special workaround for Macs.